# Import WebTrends Data to SQL Server Using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, webtrends

I need to import all the webtrends data to my local sql server database. on top of that i need to build reports.

I am very new to Webtrends, so can some one suggest me how to import the WebTrends data to my local DB Server.

Comment: How is the WebTrends data stored? Text file? CSV? Another RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

Just for context - I work at Webtrends.

My first questions is are you using the site software version or the ondemand SaaS version?  It also depends on which version.

If you're using the latest version of software the best way to go about getting things from the Webtrends Analytics product data store is to use the ODBC connector that is available for the product.  This you can download from the web UI and it installs with a single click.  I can provide more documentation, just send me an e-mail and I'll send you the actual documentation file on this.

The other method, and this is currently in beta and available only to OnDemand customers is to use the web services (REST based) that we've created.  Check out the documentation here:  http://product.webtrends.com/dxapi/index.html

Comment: Hi Adron,

I am trying to configure ODBC driver in my machine, but it is giving error as "Unable to retrieve plist". I am trying to sortout this issue with webtrends support team.We had a webex meeting they also unable to fix this issue. Presently i am using WIndows 7 and i work at Microsoft redmond campus. If you can help me to solve this issue that would be great..

Comment: I just reread this again and realized you mentioned Windows 7.  Currently the ODBC driver doesn't work with Windows 7.  My suggestion is to use the new Web Services (REST based) to pull data.  Much faster than ODBC.  :)  Let me know if this helps.